# Show a map is conformal and have some other properties

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading the following lemma in Krantz's Book.

> **Lemma.** Let $E\subset \mathbb{C}$ be compact,connected and contain more than one point.Assume that $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}\setminus E$ is connected.Then any conformal mapping $\phi :$$\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}\backslash E$$\rightarrow D$ satisfying $\phi(\infty)=0$  has the property 
>   $$|\phi'(E)|\geq \frac{\operatorname{diam}(E)}{4}$$

**Proof.** 
Let $\alpha=\phi^{'}(\infty)\neq0$. Then $\phi^{'}(0)=\frac{1}{\alpha}$.
If $\tau \in E$, then the function 
$$\psi(z)= \frac{\alpha}{\phi^{-1}(z)-\tau}$$
is holomorphic and one-to-one and satisfies $\psi(0)=0$ and $\psi^{'}(0)=1$. Thus......

---

How to show these claims about $\psi$? I am not sure what I am missing. I will be thankful if someone can give me hints.

Comment: I have succeeded in showing that $\psi(0)=0$ and as $\psi(z)$ is holomorphic  then , $\psi(z)=zg(z)$ such that $g(0)\neq 0$  $\psi^{'}(z)=zg^{'}(z)+g(z)$ .This implies $\psi^{'}(0)\neq 0$ then how I can proceed further?

Comment: @Cave Johnson Please give some remarks about this question.